# Invalid shape (64, 125, 125, 3) for image data after using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, matplotlib, keras

So I'm trying to display image that already augmented. But got `Invalid shape (64, 125, 125, 3) for image data` error. This is my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                    zoom_range=0.1,
                                    rotation_range=25,
                                    width_shift_range=0.1,
                                    height_shift_range=0.1,
                                    shear_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True,
                                    fill_mode='nearest')

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# build image augmentation generators
train_generator = train_datagen.flow(train_data, train_labels_enc, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
val_generator = val_datagen.flow(val_data, val_labels_enc, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)


from matplotlib import pyplot
for i in range(9):
    # define subplot
    pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    # generate batch of images
    batch = train_generator.next()
    # convert to unsigned integers for viewing
    image = batch[0].astype('uint8')
    # plot raw pixel data
    pyplot.imshow(image)

pyplot.show()
```

And the error pointed to `pyplot.imshow(image)`. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try `image[0,:,:,:]` that'll display the first image from a batch of 64 images. You cannot display 64 images at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `batch` object is a tuple of `(images, labels)` so if you select `batch[0]` you select all the images.

Try:

```
for i in range(9):
    pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    images, labels = train_generator.next()
    image = (images[0]*255).astype('uint8')
    pyplot.imshow(image)
```

Comment: Both you and sai answer made the error gone, but the plot only showing black image

Comment: That's because you divided the pixels by 255. See my edit